# PHP / MySQL / JSON encoding help

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am trying to implement the auto-complete script from http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/.  It's asking for JSON output like:

```
{
 query:'Li',
 suggestions:['Liberia','Libyan Arab Jamahiriya','Liechtenstein','Lithuania']
}
```

I am using PHP/MySQL.  My query to get the suggestions would be something like...

```
<?
$drug = $_GET['drug'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags_drugs WHERE drug_name LIKE '$drug%'");
    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $drug_name = $query_row['drug_name'];
        }

?>
```

This is where I'm stuck.  How do I put the array $drug_name in the suggestions and encode it for json?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$drug_name[] = $query_row['drug_name'];
```

instead of `$drug_name = $query_row['drug_name'];`

Then use

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var drugName = <?php echo json_encode($drug_name);?>
</script>
```

Use this `grugName` variable in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
json_encode($drug_name)
```

From PHP.net - [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)